# How to pull high-level server information from Mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

MySQL workbench shows the following under server stats:

[image]

I know it can grab the Connection Name and the Port from the data that I'm using to connect, but where does it grab the Host, socket, Version, Compiled For, and Running Since from? Is there a query that can grab all that information?

Answer (score 2):

This info comes from server system variables. Look in the Administration secion -> Status and System Variables:

[image]

Here I filtered for all variables that contain `version`. In plain SQL you would use this query: `select @@version`, `select @@innodb_version` etc.

Of course, some of the info is just what you specified when you defined the connection (like socket, ip, port, config file etc.).

Comment: thanks, what does the `show @@version` do (esp. the double @'s)? For me it throws an error. I have better luck doing `show variables like '%version%'`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that should have been `select @@version`. I corrected my answser. The double at sign is the prefix for system variables. A single at sign denotes user variables.